# Spark: How to create a new date string column from an epoch column?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an Apache Spark 2.x dataframe with the following columns:

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- countryCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- detail: string (nullable = true)
 |-- epoch: long (nullable = true)
```

I would like to create a new column with a date string in "yyyy-MM-dd" format based on the epoch timestamp (Unix UTC time). I will then use the date string as a partitioning column.

How do I create the column with the date string? To perform only the conversion in Java, I would use `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")`, but I am not sure how to also create the new column.

Comment: Tried `df.withColumn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method [from_unixtime](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@from_unixtime(ut:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,f:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) should be what you're looking for.  For example:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  (1, "1538384400"),
  (2, "1538481600"),
  (3, "1538588200")
).toDF("id", "epoch")

df.withColumn("date", from_unixtime($"epoch", "yyyy-MM-dd")).
  show
// +---+----------+----------+
// | id|     epoch|      date|
// +---+----------+----------+
// |  1|1538384400|2018-10-01|
// |  2|1538481600|2018-10-02|
// |  3|1538588200|2018-10-03|
// +---+----------+----------+
```